# Why block scope at global namespace is not allowed?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am curious as to why creating a block scope `{}` outside any function (in global scope) is not permitted.

I am able to do the following:

```
int main(){

  {
    int i = 4;
  }

    //other stuff

}
```

but not

```
{
    int i = 4;
}


int main(){
    //other stuff
}
```

This issue piqued my interest while implementing a compile time assert, for which I am creating a variable which is to be destroyed immediately after the assert logic is done (to free memory).

Comment: Can't you do the same thing with a namespace (if you give it a unique name).

Comment: What do you expect to accomplish, by that?

Comment: Are you aware of [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert)?

Comment: @Justin Yes, I am aware. I am implementing some core functionality/library myself in order to learn better.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Won't the object persist in memory if I do that

Comment: @User10482 `static_assert` is built into the language. You can't properly reimplement it using other language constructs. *"Won't the object persist in memory if I do that"* It will (unless you don't use it and allow the compiler to optimize it away by giving it [internal linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), e.g. by making it `static`).

Comment: Thank you guys for the input. Why does it has to always "accomplish something" to be asked on this forum. I am trying to learn programming by myself and I try to do so by implementing ideas that I have. There might be a well established library/ in-built that does this, but I want to do it myself with my idea. This teaches me a lot that I would otherwise never have learned. Why is this a problem?

Comment: @User10482  -  the purpose of a programming language is to be a tool (or a set of tools) that can be used to direct a computational device to achieve something useful.   So any features added to a programming language need to achieve *something*.   It might make some task possible that would not be possible without that feature.   It might make it easier to achieve something that could be done in other ways.    But a feature of a programming language - which will take effort to implement - that doesn't achieve anything of use is pointless and irrelevant.

Comment: @Peter I agree with what you say. But again, I believe that the learning stage should be not be bounded. "Why is it so?" is an important question to ask, and it should be asked to understand why the standard is-- what it is today. Anyways, I won't bog down this question thread too much with my personal opinions. It is a bit disheartening to get curiosity down-voted just because someone thought it is not useful to them.

Comment: @User10482 - I'm not arguing against curiosity, in learning or anything else (and I'm also not one of your down-voters).  However, your question here is not a "Why is it so?" - it is a "Why isn't this done in that way?" question, for which a perfect valid response is the question "Why would you do it that way?".   If you get that question, the person is asking you to satisfy *their* curiosity.   If your curiosity has a place, so does theirs - but you treat their curiosity as suppressing yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am curious as to why creating a block scope {} outside any function (in global scope) is not permitted.

It would be pointless and misleading.  Variables declared outside any function are statically allocated so never go out of scope (except at the end of the program).

---

**Edit:** to make a variable exist transiently on program startup, you can do something like:

```
static auto throwaway_name = [] () { MyClass myVar; return 0; } ();
```

The only thing this allocates statically is an `int` (which might get optimised out, I'm not sure).

Comment: Yep, and to try to prevent that I was trying to use a scope block to separate it out from the ```statics```

Comment: @User10482 Added a rider to my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Interesting use of lambda. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Why block scope at global namespace is not allowed?

Only declaration statements are allowed in the global namespace by the grammar. No block statements or expression statements.

Let's say that the language was changed to allow block statements in namespace scope. Think about what should the behaviour be. *When* are those statements executed? In what order?

P.S. `main` must return `int`.

Comment: Maybe behavior just like that of a block scope inside a function? The order can be after all globals, since things inside block scope are able to see outside, and not the other way. Thanks for pointing out the ```int``` for ```main```

Comment: @User10482 `Maybe behavior just like that of a block scope inside a function? ` A function is called like this: `name(arguments)`. How would the namespace scope be called? `The order can be after all globals` How about order of one block statement in namespace scope versus another block?

Comment: I meant behavior like that of a block scope inside a function (like the one inside ```main``` in the question). As for the order of two blocks, they are essentially independent of each other, so won't matter in what order they are processed

Comment: @User10482 Yes. The block scope of a function is executed when the function is called. When would the block scope in namespace scope be executed?

Comment: Is 'namespace scope' synonym for 'block scope'? I am thinking it won't be callable. It will execute once just like it does for global ```statics```. PS: I am no expert on this. Just putting out my ideas. This is a fun conversation!

Comment: @User10482 Namespace scope is where you can define free functions. For example the global namespace or a named namespace. You could try writing a proposal for the committee to see if something like this would be added to the language. You can already achieve almost the same by simply calling a function from initialisation of a global object. Though I can see that being guaranteed to be run after **all** global objects could be of some value in theory. Though I can't come up with an example use case.

Comment: >simply calling a function from initialization of a global object. You mean something like Mr. Sanders suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57829559/11205473)

Comment: @User10482 Indeed. You can also use a named function if you so prefer, or you can write a constructor for the global object.

Comment: Thanks! Also, I found a nifty trick from ```Modern C++ Design``` by Alexandrescu. He uses ```sizeof()``` and embeds the object initialization inside it with the test expression for asserting. Apparently, ```sizeof()```discards the object after it is done evaluating the expression.

Comment: Although, I am having some trouble implementing it. Maybe it's just that the language has changed a bit since the book was written.

Comment: @User10482 I don't think the expression within `sizeof` is evaluated at all. Only the type of the expression matters. Templates within the expression would be instantiated though.

Comment: You are correct. I tried it and it suffers from similar issue. I think no  standalone expressions are allowed in the global namespace (which makes sense). Here is the code [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/g5gRj6zS)

Answer (score 0):

> [`6.3.3 [basic.scope.block]`](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4810.pdf)
>  A name declared in a block (8.3) is local to that block; it has block
>   scope. Its potential scope begins at its point of declaration (6.3.2)
>   and ends at the end of its block. A variable declared at block scope
>   is a local variable

You can't have a nameless block scope in the global namespace scope.

But you can introduce a namespace

```
namespace N {
  int i = 4;
}
```

Comment: I see. but that variable would persist in the namespace, whereas ```{}``` would have destroyed it on block exit.

Comment: @User10482 I think you're stuck. To my knowledge the best you can do is make the memory lost as small as possible. Make a `char` variable and initialize it with a function that returns a `char` and do the work in the function. All of the big stuff goes out of scope with the end of the function and the only residue is the `char`.

Comment: @user4581301 Might be so. Thanks! Also, I found a nifty trick from Modern C++ Design by Alexandrescu. He uses ```sizeof()``` and embeds the object initialization inside it with the test expression for asserting. Apparently, ```sizeof()``` discards the object after it is done evaluating the expression

Comment: @User10482 I think I'll be slipping that trick into my back pocket for a trial later.

Comment: @user4581301 Well that did not go so well. It suffers from the same issue. I think no expressions are allowed in global namespace (sensibly so). You can have a look at the code [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/g5gRj6zS)